# Ignore overflow error when multiplication result is bigger than what a double can hold

Tags: vba, exception

During some iterative optimization, the following VBA code for the computation of the bivariate normal CDF sometimes throws an Overflow error on the line with `z = hx * hy * c` inside the `while` loop of the upper function.

I debugged the code and the overflow occurs when the numbers being multiplied result in a number bigger than what a double can hold.

Can you show me how to handle the problem by ignoring the iterations of the loop with such high values - I guess that's the only feasible solution (?). I tried myself with a On Error Goto nextiteration line before the multiplication and placing the nextiteration jump point before the Wend, but the error persists.

```
Function tetrachoric(x As Double, y As Double, rho As Double) As Double
    Const FACCURACY As Double = 0.0000000000001
    Const MinStopK As Integer = 20
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim c As Double
    Dim z As Double
    Dim s As Double
    Dim hx As Double
    Dim hx1 As Double
    Dim hx2 As Double
    Dim hy As Double
    Dim hy1 As Double
    Dim hy2 As Double
    Dim CheckPass As Integer

    hx = 1
    hy = 1
    hx1 = 0
    hy1 = 0
    k = 0

    c = rho
    z = c
    s = z
    CheckPass = 0

    While CheckPass < MinStopK
        k = k + 1
        hx2 = hx1
        hy2 = hy1
        hx1 = hx
        hy1 = hy
        hx = x * hx1 - (k - 1) * hx2
        hy = y * hy1 - (k - 1) * hy2
        c = c * rho / (k + 1)
        z = hx * hy * c
        s = s + z
        If Abs(z / s) < FACCURACY Then
            CheckPass = CheckPass + 1
        Else
            CheckPass = 0
        End If
    Wend
    tetrachoric = s
End Function


Public Function bivnor(x As Double, y As Double, rho As Double) As Double
'
' bivnor function
' Calculates bivariat normal CDF F(x,y,rho) for a pair of standard normal
' random variables with correlation RHO
'
If rho = 0 Then
    bivnor = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(x) * _
         Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(y)
Else
    bivnor = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(x) * _
         Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(y) + _
         Application.WorksheetFunction.NormDist(x, 0, 1, False) * _
         Application.WorksheetFunction.NormDist(y, 0, 1, False) * _
         tetrachoric(x, y, rho)
End If
End Function
```

Source: Available for download at http://michael.marginalq.com/

Answer (score 2):

you're hitting on the limits of the computer architecture. Many complex algorithms can't be implemented 1:1 with their mathematical representation because of performance reasons and/or erroneous behavior when overflowing. There's an exceptionally good blog about these issues - [John D. Cook](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/06/numbers-are-a-leaky-abstraction/).

Please take a look [here](http://www.codeplanet.eu/files/download/accuratecumnorm.pdf) for a better implementation.

You can also try binding an external library, that gives you arbitrary precision number handling, of course implemented using very expensive (in terms of CPU time) software algorithms. More can be found [here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=155129).

Comment: haha, i already knew the West article before you posted it (from Wilmott Magazine where it was published) and in fact I already use his code which is available from his website. I just wanted to have another algorithm to cross-check results and that's why I tried the above code which is by the way recommended in a book by Wiley Finance (Gunter Loeffler - Credit Risk Modeling in VBA).

Comment: John Cook's blog is excellent. You can also learn a lot by browsing his stackoverflow answers: http://stackoverflow.com/users/25188/john-d-cook

Comment: Wow, didn't know he was on SO :) Thanks jtolle!

Answer (score 1):

Updated code using `On Error Resume Next` instead of `On Error Goto`:

```
While CheckPass < MinStopK
    k = k + 1
    hx2 = hx1
    hy2 = hy1
    hx1 = hx
    hy1 = hy
    hx = x * hx1 - (k - 1) * hx2
    hy = y * hy1 - (k - 1) * hy2
    c = c * rho / (k + 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    z = hx * hy * c
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        s = s + z
        If Abs(z / s) < FACCURACY Then
            CheckPass = CheckPass + 1
        Else
            CheckPass = 0
        End If
    Else
        Err.Clear
    End If
Wend
```

Comment: just tried it, and exactly as with my own attempt (which was indeed the similar to yours except for the "On Error Goto 0"), the overflow error persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you put a `Debug.Print hx, hy, c` on the line before `z = hx * hy * c` what are the values of those three variables when you get the overflow?  The limits for doubles are ***really*** hard to hit.

Comment: The updated code I just posted runs without generating an error message, but seems to output `-1.#IND` (indeterminate) as a result value in the overflow cases.  It could be this approach is fatally flawed and you'll have to explore the options in @Vladislav's answer.

Comment: I can tell you they were extremely high, one was something like 1E+200, and the upper limit for double is ~1.7E+308, so if the other numbers were of similar magnitude, it's easy to conceive why it failed.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/float_point.aspx treats how to "Use Logarithms to Avoid Overflow and Underflow", which is a simple but quite effective way of working around overflow problems. In fact, it's so simple yet logical, why haven't we thought of that solution ourselves? ;)